# select avg, sum between rows with range

Tags: mysql, sql

- example_table

| idx | some_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 298 |
| 2 | 842 |
| 3 | 982 |
| ... | ... |
| 100 | 844 |

- range_table

| start_end_key | start_idx | end_idx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 40 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 |

How can I `select` avg or sum of example_table between rows of `start_idx` and `end_idx`

The table I want is below

| start_end_key | avg_of_some_values | sum_of_some_values | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | average of example_table between idx 1 and 2 | sum of example_table between idx 1 and 2 | 2 |
| 2 | average of example_table between idx 3 and 40 | sum of example_table between idx 3 and 40 | 38 |
| 3 | average of example_table between idx 1 and 100 | sum of example_table between idx 1 and 100 | 100 |

I've tried this

```sql
select avg(some_value), sum(some_value), count(*)
from example_table where example_table.idx between ??? and ???
```

but ??? does not allow multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how

```
select start_end_key , avg(some_value), sum(some_value) , count(*)
from example_table et
join range_table rt on et.idx between start_idx and end_idx
group by start_end_key
```